# Please! How I POST data in database using submit button using Ajax in laravel 9?

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, button, submit

Please I need your HELP...
I'm trying to send a Post request from a button using Ajax to my controller to do a create. I use laravel 9. I hope you can help me :-D

My blade____________________________________
`

```
                    Let us know a bit about Your running goals and experience so we can offer You the best training plan!
                

                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                  Take a quick survey
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Runner Survey</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="/" id="survey">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                             <label for="level" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">I would describe my current level of fitness as</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="level" id="level" form="survey" class="form-control" required autocomplete="new-level">
                                    <option value="beginner">Beginner</option>
                                    <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                                    <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                             <label for="distance" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">The distance I want to run in km is</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="distance" id="distance" form="survey" class="form-control" required autocomplete="new-distance">
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                             <label for="time" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">How many weeks do you have to achieve it?</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="time" id="time" form="survey" class="form-control" required autocomplete="new-time">
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button id="savebtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" onclick="saveForm('{{ route('forms.store')}}')">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fin Modal -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

function saveForm(route){
const request = $.ajax({
Method: 'POST',
url: route,
}).done(function(response) {
$(#savebtn).attr('form', response);
});
}

My controller______________________________________________________

```
public function store(FormsRequest $request) 
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    $name = $data['name'];
    $userId= $data['user_id'];
    $level= $data['level'];
    $time=$data['time'];
    $distance=$data['distance'];

    $result = $this->formService->store($name, $userId, $level, $time, $distance);
    return 'Created successfully!';
}
```

I need to turn in an assignment and I'm stuck...

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: I press the button, I have no errors but nothing reaches the database either.

Comment: Can I ask what is that `FormsRequest` ? is that custom >